# Enforcing method definition for templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance

I want to create small library for serialization using different protocols. So, I create "*interface*" (small abstract class) **Serializable** - each class implementing it can be then serialized:

```
class Serializable // interface
{
public:
std::string Serialize(Encoder & encoder) const
    {
    return DoSerialize(encoder);
    }

private:
virtual std::string DoSerialize(Encoder & encoder) const = 0 {}
};
```

On the other side, I have abstract version of various encoders (for different encodings):

```
class Encoder
{
public:
Serialized GetEncoded()
    {
    return DoGetEncoded();
    }

void Encode(const std::string & data)
    {
    DoEncode(data);
    }

... other encoding functions

private:
virtual Serialized DoGetEncoded() = 0 {}

virtual void DoEncode(const std::string & data) = 0 {}
};
```

And I use it like:

```
Test1 test;
test.test = "abc";

SomeEncoder enc;

cout << "Test::Serialize: " << test.Serialize(enc) << endl;
```

But maybe instead of this approach, it would be better (*why?*) to crate templated function in **Encoder**, like:

```
template<typename T>
std::string Serialize(const T & data) const
     {
     return data.Serialize();
     }

// or maybe
std::string Serialize(const Serializable & data) const
     {
     return data.Serialize();
     }
```

to present more consistent behaviour?

I have 2 questions concerning that:

1. Which approach is better (in OO terms or in general)?
2. If the second one - should I enforce users to inherit from interface or rather provide the templated version, and if someone wants his type to be serializable, he must just write those methods?

My original question was mixed - I wanted to ask if both should be achieved in the same type - enforcing to derive from interface AND use templated version, but it seems unnecesary,

Answer (score 0):

I don't really connect to any of the solutions and personally I would go with the most basic inteface :

```
struct Serializable{
   virtual std::string serialize () const = 0;
};
```

and let each class implementing it deal how serlialization is done. some classes won't even need encoder, so why force it on the function signature?

`DoSerialize` seems pretty verbose if `serialize` just calls it and return its return value, and anyway it is needed to be protected in order to work.

when keeping the interface simple you don't confuse your developers- they don't have to understand how you intended the serialization to work - they simply serialize their objects to some binary form.

Comment: The Do... versions are for NVI, and those one-lines are considered in encoders and not in every object.
Each class needs encoder because classes do not know in which format they will be written and where.

One more thing: it is now up to users which serialiazation format they use - they only instantiate encoder they want, and I do all the work for them. Serialize() in object only calls function based on class atributes/data.